# Which amiibo figures can I use to get Wolf Link in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf, amiibo

I wanted to know which specific amiibo figures are used to get Wolf Link in ACNL. I read that you can use a Link, Wolf link, or Zelda amiibo figure. I see that there's different Link amiibo figures (SSB, Archer, Twilight Princess, etc.), but which ones should work? Do all of them work?

Answer (score 0):

For Wolf Link, you can use Zelda (Sm4sh) and probably all Link amiibo (Sm4sh, BotW, Wolf Link).